Is there a mate-in-three position where the two first moves of the winning side must be quiet to not delay the mate?
Is there a position where w.l.o.g. white is to move, it has a mate in three, and no matter what black does, white's two first moves must be quiet (i.e., without check or capture) in order not to delay the checkmate?

Here is an example for mate-in-two: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/14001/33457 (first diagram of the answer).

Three? I'm just too lazy to send you half of the SCHWALBE #3 originals! I bet the score can be pushed far higher.
Romeo Bedoni, Andre Cheron, Journal de Geneve 28/06/1975, #57
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "7n/ppp2p2/2N2Pp1/6B1/8/8/p1p2PKp/rbNk1rbR w - - 0 1"]

Note that the first capturing move pair Kxf1 bxc6 was added only later to increase the move numbers. Simply drop it again to have a #56 fulfilling your needs. Also note a big defect: it doesn't matter in which order you play the tempo-losing K-f3-g3-g2.
Solution
A "cleaner" example: Mate in 18.
Pierre-Antoine Cathignol, diagrammes 1987-1988, 2. Preis
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "8/8/8/2b3p1/5pPk/4pPp1/2N1PpP1/5K2 w - - 0 1"]

Solution
A study by Shinkman 1905, 97 moves until mate, unfortunately the pawn structure is illegal:
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "bn2B3/rn2Bp1p/p6p/k2N1p2/7p/2bp1p2/5P2/3K3N w - - 0 1"]

A study by F. Lindgren 1917, 24 moves:
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "8/8/5N2/8/3p1K1k/3N4/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

Solution to the studies and THX to all contributors from MatPlus (same thread).

Oh, it is not as complicated as I thought it would be! Do you think it would be tricky if we only allowed mate-in-three positions where all non-"quiet" non-checkmate white moves make white lose the win? Anyway, great answer! Thank you!

This then would be an unexpected-mate-study. I know tons of them too (and just would have to check that they don't check - sorry :-) - or capture.).

Without the pawn White has a checkless mate in 7. Is there a mate in 7 or less that incudes a check?

at everyone: since there is considerable interest, I take it to the experts at MatPlus. I'll edit my answer accordingly.
